# C++ - Destructor is called more times than expected

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, destructor

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class C1
{   public:

        C1(){ cout<<"CONSTR WAS HERE"<<endl; }

        C1(const C1&ob){ cout<<"COPY CONSTR WAS HERE"<<endl; }

        ~C1(){ cout<<"DESTR WAS HERE"<<endl; }
}

void f1(C1 x){  }

int main()
{
    C1 c1;
    f1(c1);
}
```

If we run the code as it is, we get:

```
CONSTR WAS HERE
COPY CONSTR WAS HERE
DESTR WAS HERE
DESTR WAS HERE
```

Which is perfectly understandable from my point of view. However, if we modify the function "f1" to:

> C1 f1(C1 x){  }

instead of

> void f1(C1 x){  }

we get:

```
CONSTR WAS HERE
COPY CONSTR WAS HERE
DESTR WAS HERE
DESTR WAS HERE
DESTR WAS HERE
```

and I am not quite sure why.

Comment: `C1 f1(C1 x){ }` has undefined behavior because it doesn't actually return a value.

Comment: If you declare a function to return something (i.e. the return type is anything other than `void`) then the function *must* return something, or you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (which makes your program ill-formed and invalid). Speculating about any kind of behavior in a program with UB is a moot point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enable your warnings:

> warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in your program, which means that anything can happen. The compiler is likely "returning an undefined instance of `C1` here", which causes the destructor to be called.

The program might crash or do **anything else** depending on your compiler/flags/machine.

Answer (score 9):

Modify `C1 f1(C1 x){}` to actually return something and your output will be as expected ([Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uUgsTcoeX8w1FOIa))

```
C1 f1(C1 x){ return {};}
```

> CONSTR WAS HERE 
>   COPY CONSTR WAS HERE
>   CONSTR WAS HERE
>   DESTR WAS HERE
>   DESTR WAS HERE
>   DESTR WAS HERE

Otherwise your code exhibits undefined behavior.